# Is there a way to control window height on mobile with CSS or jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, css, ios, mobile

I've got some problems with window height in mobile browser.
I'm using css `100vw` but it's not always exact - especially when browser shows additional functionality - i mean navigation bar on top or functional buttons on the bottom.

In simple words - they've take away the size of the window but it does not refer to exact computed window size.

I'm putting videos for best reffer of what i'm talking about:
[As you can see here - where i'm opening chat window the window height is changing during keyboard show-up - but window itself does not change the size - when i enter it second time - the window height is changing - how i can get controll over it?](https://tomb.pl/video/IMG_5785.MP4)

[Here when the bottom stripe is added the height of the chat window is ok - it's computed by CSS `height:calc(100vh - px)` and it's work](https://tomb.pl/video/IMG_5789.MP4)
[But when stripe is gone - window height remain the same - so the height is much lower](https://tomb.pl/video/IMG_5790.MP4)

How can i get the height of the mobile window with additional functionalities of this window? (adress bar, function buttons or keyboard added?).

(Movies came from iPhone iOS - it's seems everything work's fine on Android)

Comment: You mean pull / stretch the length of a phone? Just kidding. Is it possible to use percent for example "100%"?

Comment: @GenoChen the problem is - that opening window is inside the container - if i use "100%" i'll get the height of the container - not the window itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `100vw`, try using `100%`. Like this:

`height:100%`

Comment: Thank you for answear - but the problem is that element that i'm trying to style is inside the container - so if i make it 100% it get's the height of the container - not the window itself.

Comment: Ok, i just removed the thing from the container - thanks - i hope it works.